# Join two dataframes by range and values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like this:

df1:

| Value | Responsible |
| --- | --- |
| 11000 | Jack |
| 21040 | Dylan |
| 12050 | Jack |

df2:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20000 |
| 20001 | 30000 |

Desired output:

| Start | End | Responsible |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20000 | Jack |
| 20001 | 30000 | Dylan |

I need to join the 'Responsible' column in df2, using 'Value' as key that is in the range set by 'Start' and 'End'. Let's define that 'Value' has unique 'Responsible' for each range, but there are repeated values of 'Responsibles' in df1 (again, just one for each range).

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: @C.Pappy done, sorry, forgot about that

Comment: Do the intervals overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the smallest `Value` that is larger than `Start`, then make sure it is smaller than `End`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[11000,21040,12050], 'Responsible':['Jack', 'Dylan', 'Jack']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start':[10001,20001], 'End':[20000, 30000]})

df = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('Start'), df1.sort_values('Value'),
                   left_on = 'Start', right_on = 'Value', direction='forward')
df = df[df['Value']<df['End']].drop(columns = 'Value')
```

```
    Start   End     Responsible
0   10001   20000   Jack
1   20001   30000   Dylan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate bins from `df2` and then bin your data in `df1` based on those.

Then you can sort according to "Value" and `drop_duplicates` to select each row who has the minimum value from each bin.

```py
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2["Start"], df2["End"])
out = (
    df1.assign(bins=pd.cut(df1["Value"],bins=bins))
    .sort_values("Value")
    .drop_duplicates(subset="bins")
)

print(out)
   Value Responsible            bins
0  11000        Jack  (10001, 20000]
1  21040       Dylan  (20001, 30000]
```

If you would like to perform some post-processing to get your data formatted exactly as your output is you can do:

```py
final = (
    out.assign(
        start=lambda d: d["bins"].cat.categories.left,
        end=lambda d: d["bins"].cat.categories.right
    )
    .drop(columns=["Value", "bins"])
)

print(final)
  Responsible  start    end
0        Jack  10001  20000
1       Dylan  20001  30000
```